# Suspicious IPs (64.19.142.11, 64.19.142.13 apparently from Verizon) prepended to all image URL's in CSS

Tags: php, css

I noticed that when I open a CSS through a browser I see that all my images have some IP prepended to them. It looks like this:

> url(http://64.19.142.11/www.mydomain.com/i/pgBg.png)

In reality, my CSS is using relative path:

> url(/i/pgBg.png)

What happen? What's causing this? Was my site hacked and some server overwrite rule was added? It seem to affect only CSS, because the images in the page are fine.

Comment: Only the images? Or other files as well?

Comment: Is your site visible somewhere ? If not can you make a fiddle ?

Comment: I found it in CSS only, so far. The IP changes too from http://64.19.142.11 to http://64.19.142.13

Comment: When I access CSS file directly it looks fine, but when I view page source via browser and click on CSS (in FF) I get weird results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two IP addresses are registered to [Flash Networks](http://www.flashnetworks.com/) (see [here](http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/64.19.142.11) and [here](http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/64.19.142.13)).

Your CSS is probably being modified by their [web acceleration service](http://www.flashnetworks.com/Content.aspx?Page=web_optimization) to point to a cached copy of your images on their servers.

If you didn't set this up yourself, you will need to consult your server manager or hosting company for more information.

**EDIT:** [Apparently](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/verizon-broadband-security-threat-or-just-abuse-690596/) Verizon is/was doing something with that web acceleration service. [**This**](http://www.verizonbusiness.com/Medium/products/itinfrastructure/acceleration/options.xml) may also be relevant.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that the issue went away. The weird thing is that I don't even use Verizon and use a different provider for internet access. Whatever Verizon did, was messing my site...

Comment: @santa Certainly very strange. Glad to hear it went away.

Comment: Thanks for all this research. I need to put these IP's in subject line. I am sure others get affected by this rouge Verizon activity. It seems the issue goes as far back as 2008.

Comment: @XuqiciAcerto disabling firefox cache helped me. I think that forces a reload of the original css. I still don't know for sure what's causing the IP injection. I asked my hosting company as Xenon suggests but they don't work with Flash Networks.